# Como acerta o comando do order by?

Tags: sql, oracle

Eu digitei o seguinte comando no oracle;

```
select * from emp where ndep in(10,30);
```

e tive isso como resultado;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ele está tudo certo, o problema é que queria colocar ele na ordem decrescente do numero de departamento;

essas foram minhas tentativas;

tentativa 1º;

```
select * from emp where ndep in(10,30) | order by ndep desc;
```

tentativa 2º

```
select * from emp where ndep in(10,30)  order by ndep desc;
```

tentativa 3º

```
select * from emp where ndep in(10,30) and  order by ndep desc;
```

Não tive sucesso.

Como faço para acertar o comando?

///////////////////////atualizando a postagem

```
select * from emp
where ndep in(10,30) 
and  
order by ndep desc;
```

essa foi a mensagem de erro;

ORA-00936: expressão não encontrada
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:
*Action:
Erro na linha: 3 Coluna: 5

Comment: O `ndep desc` resultou em que? Deviria funciona, o que deu errado?

Comment: acabei de atualizar a postagem, dá uma olhada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tira o `and`

Fica assim:

```
select * from emp
where ndep in(10,30) 
order by ndep desc;
```

Fiddle com o SQL rodando [aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5dc088/2).